# "Build Solution" not working in Visual C++ anymore

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, build

I'm working on a personal project in Visual C++ 2008 and for some reason "Build Solution" doesn't work anymore...the code changes aren't registered unless I use "Rebuild Solution".

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

I've tried google, but found nothing useful...

Answer (score 3):

Did you check to ensure that all of the projrcts are set to compile in the configuration manager?  (Right click on the SLN in the Solution Explorer and choose "Configuration Manager".
Also, I ran across this once on a VS2008 solution and "fixed" it by converting it to a .Net 2.0 solution and back to a 3.5 solution.

Comment: All the projects are set to compile.  How did you convert it to a .Net 2.0 solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try "Clean Solution" - that will delete any output files that might have dodgy timestamps on them.

("Rebuild" ought to imply "Clean", but you never know.)

Comment: Clean Solution works, but the next time I do a 'build' it still doesn't work.

I have to either use clean solution or rebuild solution every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the timestamps on your files.  Are they stamped at some point in the past?  That would cause this particular problem to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Pls. check if all the projects are loaded (Managed/unmanaged) in the solutions. In my application code, a reference to one of the C++ projects was missing. Re-referenced and it worked for me. Try this.