# Build does not work, need rebuild

Tags: visual-c++, build, ide

This is really frustrating, I am using Visual Studio 2012 for C++ for a project, and it worked fine for a while. Then out of the blue, it started having problems. 
The build function does not update the project anymore. I need to do a REBUILD every time I modify anything in my project.

I have looked all over for a solution, but none helped. First of all, I didn't change any settings, but I looked anyway. Tools/Options/Build&Run, Project/Config Manager, you name it I have checked it. It doesn't look like it's a settings problem.

Another thing though, on other forums, I have read that this MIGHT be because of a bad include, that the file included is not there anymore, or something like that. But that is not possible either since I didn't delete any file from the project. But, this problem seems more plausible since, the project at a much earlier stage, had less includes, and it still works.

So, can you help me solve this problem? It is really annoying since most of the solutions out there are NOT working!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have run into an issue like this it is usually something like missing project dependencies.  You may want to take a look at ["Build Solution" not working in Visual C++ anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185499/build-solution-not-working-in-visual-c-anymore?rq=1). If you are able to share your solution someone may be able to take a look at it.